# How do i save after typing in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I have a problem trying to save an emacs file. I need to know how to save the buffer in emacs.If there is any resource for all emacs commands, please share the link.

Comment: You need to work through the built-in tutorial. Type `C-h t` (meaning `Ctrl+h` followed by `t`) to begin the tutorial.

Comment: Your edit completely invalidated the answer and comment.  If you have a new question, please use the "Ask Question" button.  I've reverted your change for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to know how to save a buffer in emacs.

Use `C-x C-s`. That means `Ctrl-x` followed by `Ctrl-s`. You can keep the `Ctrl` key held down between `x` and `s` if desired.

> If there is any resource for all emacs commands, please share the link.

Take a look at [this previous StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601206/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-currently-available-commands-and-hotkeys) question for some guidance.